# Help identifying a wordless Boat Voyage book

Tags: story-identification

It was a weird book with a nice artstyle that had no words.

I believe it was about a cruise that eventually crashed or something, and as it progressed weird and strange things befell the crew and passengers. I believe there was a scene with purple apes and a stone carving of an ape as well.

Read around 2006 - 2008.

Comment: Ah. So not *Zoom*, which was my first guess.